# Single page application. Security for template management

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, single-page-application

In my application i have WEB-UI in single page (AngularJS) and server rest services. *server implemented using spring boot, java annotation configuration, security is turn on*. I can manage rest responses on server part using security restrictions role based.

Similar issue for angular controller templates. **For same request server should return different angular templates if roles are different**.

How last issue should be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can just create action in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="template.html")
public String home(HttpServletRequest request){

    if (request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
        return "/template1.html";
    } else {
        return "/template2.html";
    }

}
```

Maybe you would also need to configure `ViewResolver` (it depends on your configuration).

Comment: Idea is good for very beginning or if application contains only one or two urls to process, but if you have a lot of similar situations, solution should be complex. There is should be factory builder to configure all situations in same place, you can not manage it on controller level. Proposed way can be used for tests only i think.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch templates around by implementing a function whenever you use templateUrl. For instance:

Instead of this:

```
...
templateUrl: "template.html"
...
```

Try this:

```
...
templateUrl: function() {
                 if( ... ) return "template1.html"
                 else return "template2.html";
               }
```

This applies to directives, routes, etc.

PS: By no means this is supposed to be a secure way of hiding templates.

Comment: sure i can. but problem is complex. I should not manage on client permission based restrictions. This filter should be on server i think.

Comment: but any way following your idea, how client can know which template for same group it needs for current session?

Comment: @Sergii: The real security must be in server methods. But the IHM is not part of the security, its only role is to avoid to display links or buttons to simple users that would lead to 403 when clicked. It is fine on a security point of view to change template on client based on apparent role **provided the actual security is implemented on server**. As you use spring-security, I would use method security on service layer.

Comment: @Sergii as Serge explained, you can't ever be secure in a web environment if you templates are exposed to any http get. You really have to close that door on your backend, only allowing the templates get to the client side when rules allow.

Comment: @wdanda, i know i can not use security on web, but your solutions needs some security information to resolve conditions. This is first main reason why i do not agree with your answer. My comment questions pointed to it. I need server side solution to process _**For same request server should return different angular templates if roles are different.**_

Answer (score 0):

I have got an architect idea.

To solve this issue should be used **[UrlBasedViewResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html)** to create\configure special **CustomSecurityBasedInternalResourceViewResolver**.

How to implement custom view resolver please check [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38614453/spring-security-4-customsecurityinternalresourceviewresolver) or provide you solution.