# Spring Security 4. CustomSecurityInternalResourceViewResolver

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, single-page-application, embedded-resource

I need configure my spring-boot web application to return *different templates for same URL*. Template should be returned checking roles for current user.

To solve this issue i think should be used **[UrlBasedViewResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html)** to create\configure special ***CustomSecurityBasedInternalResourceViewResolver***. It will be really good if someone will show how to implement this idea.